# KendoUI datepicker input field display issue

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, datepicker

Hopefully what I provide here will be sufficient to assist me in a display issue I'm having.

---

> You can see this in action at: **http://dev.skoovy.com** 
>   **Username:** test@test.com 
>   **Password:** test123

It's the form at the top of the page.  This is an in development site.

---

When I set up an input field to provide a datepicker, it changes the input field to contain this added area next to the calendar icon.  I cannot find out why this is happening.

**Here is what it looks like with datepicker initialized.  The areas highlighted with the red pen are what I'm trying to fix.**

[image: input fields with datepicker initialized]

**And, here is what it lookslike without datepicker initialized.**

[image]

**Here is the HTML as copied from the debugger pane in Chrome (via element selector)**

```
<div class="when_range_input" style="display: block;">
Start: <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header" style=""><span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default"><input type="text" id="when_range_start" name="wv_drs" value="" data-role="datepicker" class="k-input" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="when_range_start_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-label="Current focused date is null" style="width: 100%;"><span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="when_range_start_dateview"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span></span></span></span>
&nbsp;End: <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header" style=""><span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default"><input type="text" id="when_range_end" name="wv_dre" value="" data-role="datepicker" class="k-input" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="when_range_end_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-label="Current focused date is null" style="width: 100%;"><span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="when_range_end_dateview"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span></span></span></span>
</div>
```

**Here is the css I'm using:**

```
.when_range_input {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:350px;
    /** margin-left:320px; **/
    border-color:#ffcc00;
    padding:5px;
    z-index:9999;
    font-size:11px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.55);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.55);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.55);
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.when_range_input input[type="text"] {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #e2e2e2;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #b8b8b8;
    padding: 2px 1px 2px 1px;
    line-height: 15px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: PLease provide us a demo link

Comment: I have updated the post to include link and login to dev site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the max-width of the input field

```
.headersearch-flex-container .searchfld.flex-item:nth-child(2) input {
  width: 90px;
  max-width: 110px;
  min-width: 80px;
}
```